# How to correctly include scripts per page

Tags: requirejs

I have many shared scripts that all my pages use, such as jquery and other frameworks.

But some pages have 1 script file just for that page. Eg: Index.html will have a corresponding index.js file.

My original idea was to do something like this :

```
 <script data-main="script/includes" src="./script/require.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./escript/index.js"></script>
```

But in this case, I think index.js loads before require has done it's work, so that doesn't help me.

What I want to do is load up all the shared stuff, and then load up page specific stuff.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

you could add requirejs config to you startup or app file as follow

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-1.10.2",
        "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui-1.11.4",
        "General": "General",
        "knockout": "knockout-3.4.0.debug",
        "komapping": "knockout.mapping-latest.debug",
        "modernizr": "modernizr-2.8.3",
        "respond": "respond",
        "underscore": "underscore",
        "datatable": "DataTables/jquery.dataTables",
        "bootstrap": "bootstrap",
        "bootstrap-dialog": "bootstrap-dialog",
        "bootstrap-datepicker": "bootstrap-datepicker"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery.appender": ["jquery"],
        "jquery.textReplacer": ["jquery"],
        "jquery-ui": {
            "deps": ["jquery"],
            "exports": "$"
        },
        "bootstrap-responsive": {
            "deps": ["bootstrap", "respond"],
            "exports": "bootstrap-responsive"
        },
        "komapping": {
            "deps": ["knockout"],
            "exports": "komapping"
        },
        "bootstrap": {
            "deps": ["jquery"],
            "exports": "bootstrap"
        },
        "bootstrap-dialog": {
            "deps": ["bootstrap", "jquery"],
            "exports": "bootstrap-dialog"
        }
    }
});
```

you can create separate file and  include after require js as follow

```
    <script src="./Scripts/app.js"></script>
```

And In you page specific file just inject names and it will load in the order you specify.

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'pagespecific path', "knockout-delegatedEvents"],
function ($, ko, viewmodel,koevent) {
    $(function () {

    });
});
```